# Current Date automated field

Tags: mysql, date

Hi I am trying to create a field within a MySQL table that stores the date on which the record was entered.

I am doing this using the following trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `radia`.`orderstable_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `orderstable`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET
NEW.Date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This gives me an SQL syntax error.

Furthermore I have tried to set the default value of the column to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but this returns the date plus the time. I want only the date to show up. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: "I want only the date to show up."

Can't you just handle that on the display end?

Comment: I am outputting a report using iReport. I would much rather have it such that only the date is stored within the database. If there is a way to do that.

Comment: Of course there is. You use data type that's intended for saving dates. It's called `date`. If you can't alter the table and change the data type, then you handle display either at query level or at the language level which pulls the info from MySQL.